# how to make a selenium project run on a build of another project before it's deployed using gitlab CI

Tags: selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, devops, gitlab-ci

So this is a question of concept more than technical,
Say I have two projects project A is the project that I'm testing, it's a website that is built with angular 8, and project B is the selenium testing framework that has all my testing scripts that will run on project A,
NOW  both projects are on GitLab in separate repositories.
Question 1:
on a merge, for project A  with new code, a build will happen with the new code and if successful then I want to trigger the build of project B and run the tests on project A's new build

( is it possible ?)

Question 2 :
if it is possible how do I access the build of project A when I have already defined the URLs that selenium will run the scripts on?
thank you in advance for whoever is willing to help and I'm sorry if this question is considered a dumb question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CI/CD tool to achieve this (ex: Jenkins, Bamboo, Teamcity,CircleCI, Gitlab etc)
You will need to configure a job to deploy app A, (you can provide any source and configure the deployment) then you can do the same with app B. Even if you are building the app on localhost, or you deploy it in another place, you can keep environment variables in your automation framework.